# Creating a unique ID column for the following table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I would like to generate a unique ID column for the following table:

I am not sure how to do it as each column has null values

```
FromCompany Container   Numbers     ToCompany        Location
DISCOVERY   HALU 330308   5         MAGNA CHARGE     St-Laurent
            ATSU 827944   0         LEEZA DIST. 
                          4     
COLUMBIA    CAIU 807457   3         La Cie Canada    Baie D'Urfe
                          6     
                          0
```

Comment: Is it a real table? Or the result of a query?

Comment: Of course that doesn't solve the real issue as per your other question, because you don't know what order the id will be assigned - and its the order you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an identity column for your table.

```
Alter Table t
Add Id Int Identity(1, 1)
```

more comprehensive example

> ```
> create table t(col1 int);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values (1), (2), (5)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> Alter Table t
> Add Id Int Identity(1, 1)
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | Id
> ---: | -:
>    1 |  1
>    2 |  2
>    5 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cae3429385ff18b8098ed77615a4dca7)*